# Multi user sign in Asp.net MVC4 web application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, web-applications

I created an asp.net mvc4 application and depolyed it successfully in server.

When I login into the  deployed web application its working fine, but when different user login from different device with their own credential,by surprise my page is visible to them. They cant access their profile instead of that my profile details are displaying to them.

Once after I logged out they can view their pages and its happening vice versa.

I am dumping my head to figure out the problem.

Controller.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(ECusertables user,int id=0)
    {
            if (IsValid(user.Email, user.Password))
            {
                user = db.ECusertables.Where(u => u.Email == user.Email).Select(i =>             i).FirstOrDefault();                                                          

                 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
             }
    } @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)  //View.Cshtml
    {
        <div align="right" style="margin-removed10px;">  @Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name) 
        </div>
    }
```

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Have you checked what the user id is for the user that is logging in on the different devices?

Comment: @Maccle415 yes its auto increment id from databse.

Comment: what I meant though is if you log in with the two users does it return the correct id for each user or does it return the same id for both users?